# Complex analysis. proving given function is harmonic on the region it is defined

Tags: complex-analysis

So I'm stuck again, with a problem involving how to prove if a function is harmonic on the region it is defined.

The question: Verify that each given function is harmonic (in the region where it is defined) and then find a harmonic conjugate of $u$.

$u = \Im(e^{z^2})$, I know how to find the harmonic conjugate v(x,y) but how do I prove it is harmonic? I know I can use laplace-equation but notice that my secondary partial derivates are really long, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you found a $v$ such that $v + iu$ is analytic, then the CR-equations are satisfied: $v_x = u_y$, $v_y = -u_x$. So $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = (-v_y)_x + (v_x)_y = -v_{yx} + v_{xy} = 0$. Thus, $u$ is harmonic. Generally if $u$ is the real part (or imaginary part) of an analytic function, then $u$ is harmonic.

Comment: So if I can prove that e^(z^2) is analytic, then I have also proven that u and v are harmonic, I think I get that part, but how do I prove that (e^(z^2)) is analytic? Is there an easy way to do that,?

Comment: The function $z\mapsto e^{z^2}$ is the composition of analytic functions $z\mapsto e^z$ and $z\mapsto e^z$, therefore it's analytic.

Comment: I'm sorry for being so slow, but what does that mean, z-->e^(z), and is it obvious that the function e^(z) is analytic, and how would you prove that in case it is true ?

Comment: @Krantz The notation $z\mapsto e^z$ is another way of writing the function $f(z) = e^z$. In any case, you don't actually need to prove directly that $e^{z^2}$ is analytic. You find that for $z = x + yi$, $u = e^x \sin y$, and a harmonic conjugate $v$ is $v = e^x\cos y$. Then $u$ and $v$ satisfy those CR-equations, and by my argument above, that implies $u$ is harmonic.

Comment: If I'm understanding you right here, this would mean that as long as I can find a (u) and a (v) that satisfy the CR-equations, that would mean that both of them is harmonic, I'm just curious, lets say that u=xy, isnt it always possible to find a v that makes both of them satisfy those CR-equations? Thanks for the answers!

Comment: @Krantz if $u$ and $v$ are real-differentiable functions and satisfy the CR-equations, then $u$ and $v$ are harmonic. With $u = xy$, we would find that $v$ takes the form $\frac{1}{2}y^2 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + C$ where $C$ is a constant.